# Java: Show JPopupMenu without passing an invoker component

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

When I let popup a JPopupMenu without passing the "invoker component", the menu doesn't work: submenu's don't open and isn't getting repainted. But when I create a completely useless JFrame with a JLabel inside, and I pass the JLabal as invoker, it works correctly...

Any suggestions, how to avoid creating a useless frame. And my application really hasn't any frames open, it just has to popup a simple menu.

```
JPopupMenu.show(null, xOnTheScreen, yOnTheScreen); // Doesn't work
JPopupMenu.show(aStupidJLabelInAStupidJFrame, x, y); // Works
```

Thanks

Comment: Your swing app has to be in some JPanel, at the very least. Isn't it?

Comment: If you use the popup menu as popup for a desktop tray icon, you will have no component to use for the invoker parameter. I remember having a similiar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `JPopupMenu` source code and you'll see why you have to set an invoker.

Showing a popup menu without any existing component would be very bad usability, in the same league as popup windows from a browser.

Why can't you use `JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`, or add a mouse listener to the component in which you want to show popup menu?

Comment: Search for `JPopupMenu#getInvoker` in JDK6 you'll see a whole bunch of references. It's really not a good idea to change such a basic behavior and assumption.